# Equivalence verification using Lava

Tags: haskell, formal-verification, equivalence, lava

I've been trying to verify equivalence property between two circuits in Chalmers Lava. I have declared a type bit:

```
type Bit = Signal Bool
```

And I have two circuits each has a list of bits as input and a tuple of lists of bits, and a function that checks their equivalence:

```
circuit1:: [Bit] ->([Bit],[Bit])
circuit2:: [Bit] ->([Bit],[Bit])
propEquiv input = ok
    where 
        out1 = circuit1 input 
        out2 = circuit2 input 
        ok = out1 <==> out2
```

These two circuits take inputs as lists of 64 elements. 
I was able to simulate them with one input using simulate, ans simulate them with multiple using simulateSeq, but for the hole domain i wasn't able and I got this error:

```
<interactive>:7:20:
    No instance for (Finite [Bit]) arising from a use of `domain'
    In the second argument of `simulateSeq', namely `domain'
    In the expression: simulateSeq ipSpec domain
    In an equation for `it': it = simulateSeq ipSpec domain
```

(in line 7 i have the type declaration)

Also for the propEquiv, I can simulate it, but I couldn't verify it using satzoo, and i got this error:

```
*Main> satzoo propEquiv 
<interactive>:9:1:
    No instance for (Fresh [Bit]) arising from a use of `satzoo'
    In the expression: satzoo propEquiv
    In an equation for `it': it = satzoo propEquiv
*Main>
```

I counldn't understand both of them neither find anything when searching on the web, can someone help me with this? i tried to define the circuits with 64 elemnts in stand of a list , but it didn't work.

Regards.

Comment: There's no good way to fix the first error; indeed, a `[Bit]` is not finite. You'll have to rethink your approach. The second error is easier; define an instance `Fresh a => Fresh [a]`

Comment: Can you tighten the type of `circuit1` and `circuit2` to express the fact that they both require 64 `Bit`s of input, not an arbitrary number? E.g. using [`vector-sized`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-sized)? Then it shouldn't be too difficult to make an `instance (Finite a, KnownNat n) => Finite (Vector n a)`.

Comment: @Cactus yes that' what I am trying to do, as I am not familier with Haskell, I couln't figure out what was the problem when I use vector.sized. Thank you for your response.